# CSS centre a div with nested divs to the true center of the Browser without specifying widths

Tags: html, css, centering

OMG, Really I've been here a thousand times before. I am so going to snippet this answer.
I cannot believe how hard it is to do something as easy as this.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="class1">Page 1 of 1</>
         <div class="class1"> — </>
         <div class="class1">Next</>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need the wrapper to be dead centre to the browser. Doesn't matter what the length of the text within is, or the amount of divs. How on earth does one do this?! I'm freaking out here. I'm not that bad at CSS. Googling this turns up forum posts from 2005. Or answers are found because the width was specified so that's just cheating.

Hair is being pulled out!

I won't put my CSS in here cos it's just not working, theres no point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6utN2/1/

I think you'd have been better off coding this with a `UL` and using the `LI` for your 3 elements.

Here's why: `.wrapper` MUST act as the container for those 3 `divs` because you've floated them - taking them out of the document flow.

The only way to reign in the problem caused by this is to wrap your wrapper...which is not the leanest solution one could write.

The `UL` technique works great here, though not that intuitive at first, BUT the `UL` is the container, `LI`s can all float left (and will stay nested within their parent). Finally, a single div could be used to span whatever element the `UL` resides, and center it.

ps - I used .fauxBody as the wrapping wrapper - just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks a bunch dawson, this is exactly what I needed. So saving this snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something, but [why does this not work for you?:](http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/F25u6/)

```
.wrapper {
     text-align:center;   
}
```

You said your CSS wasn't relevant, so either this is too easy or I'm missing something. Then again - sometimes the simplest solution is the best one.

If you need the inner divs displayed a certain way, you didn't mention it - so I didn't include it.

> OK didn't specify that the divs within need to float next to each other

[OK, then use `display:inline` on the inner divs:](http://jsfiddle.net/F25u6/2/)

```
.wrapper div {
    display:inline;
}
```

*"But I need them displayed `block` and they MUST be floated!"*

[OK, then just float them and use a clearfix](http://jsfiddle.net/F25u6/4/) if you need it.

```
.wrapper:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

This still works fine floating the inner divs without the clearfix, but you didn't provide a mockup of what you wanted so it makes answering this question more difficult.

IMO `float` is used in many situations where it is not needed, which can cause a lot of layout problems. It's a very poorly understood property and gets abused regularly.

Comment: OK didn't specify that the divs within need to float next to each other.

Comment: random question, are my questions rubbish? I never get upvoted. I know some of them arent deserving but i hink a q like this is pretty useful.Just wondering out aloud, ater using stackoverflow for a year now. Man what an incredible service.

Comment: Heh don't worry about it man! But.. in this case you left out details that you later pointed out to be relevant, didn't show any code, didn't say what you tried, started your question with `OMG`, and it's an easy question about css. Not very interesting perhaps. Yeah I agree this site is great, I've been using it 2-3 weeks now and have learned a lot. Plus it makes me feel at home when I land here after a google search :)

Answer (score 0):

without specifying a width? Without specifying a width on the wrapper it will be 100% of the body. If you do set a width you only need:

```
#wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a `div` is a block-level element, it needs to have a width specified to take less than 100% of the browser's width. Typically, with a defined `width` you could use `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` (`top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`) to centre the `div`.

Failing that, you could use:

```
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Which reduces the `#wrapper` `div` to the width of its contents, and *then* centres it in the window. This is not compatible with IE < 7, I believe, as a `div` [does not, 'naturally,' have a `display: inline`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03).

Comment: Neither of these answers come anywhere close, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/6utN2/